# Bootstrap 3 Tabs working locally but not on remote server

Tags: javascript, php, apache, twitter-bootstrap-3, lamp

I've inherited a LAMP project that uses Bootstrap 3.3.7's tabs. The tabs work fine when I run it locally, but when trying to run it on the remote server, the content fails to update when you click on a tab. It's not completely unresponsive - the tab that's been clicked is highlighted like it's activated and when you click on a tab and then back to the first tab, the content fades in again - but the actual content is never replaced.

I've made sure that jQuery is imported before Bootstrap and I've tried importing both jQuery and Bootstrap locally and from CDNs. The imports are currently:

```
<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

The tabs menu is formatted like this:

```
<div class="side-nav-container">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav side-nav">
        <li>
            <a class="side-nav-button" id="link_dashboard_tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#row_user_dashboard">
                Dashboard
            </a>
        <li>
            <a class="side-nav-button" id="link_my_action_tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#row_user_myaction">
                My Action
            </a>
        </li>
    </li>
... more tabs ...
    </ul>
</div>
```

The content is like this (where each `include` statement references a php file in the same folder):

```
<div id="page-wrapper">
    <div class="container-fluid tab-content ">
        <div id="row_user_dashboard" class="row tab-pane fade in active">
            <?php include 'dashboard.php'?>
        </div>
        <div id="row_user_myaction" class="row tab-pane fade">
            <?php include 'dashboard-myactions.php' ?>
        </div>
...more content...
    </div>
</div>
```

I know the server is definitely reading the Bootstrap JS, because when the import is commented out, the href from the tab is added to the URL. When the import is active, this doesn't happen.

There's another page in this project that uses tabs and they work fine there. However, it just has all its content dumped into one big php file, with no `include` statements, which leads me to believe the problem might have something to do with the `include` statements, but there's a lot of content on this page that uses them and renders fine.

**Edit**: it's not the includes. I tried copying and pasting the code from a referenced PHP file straight into this one; it didn't fix the problem.

The server (Ubuntu 20.04) is running Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu) and PHP 7.4.3. My local (macOS 10.15.7) is running Apache/2.4.46 (Unix) and PHP 7.4.11. I tried updating the server versions to match my local but it claims to have the latest.